# Isolating $x$ from $y = (x-1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(Yeah I deleted an earlier question about this, I had everything wrong in it)

I'm trying to find the value of $x$

$$y = (x-1)^2$$

Can I

$$\sqrt{y} = (x-1)$$

?

Comment: There is no "the value of x": the first equation above gives you a parabola pointing upwards with the vertex at $(1,0)$, so there are infinitely many solution pairs.

Comment: @Lost: It seems reasonable to assume that $y$ is given.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Possibly, just wanted to make sure that was clear.

Comment: Don't delete the question, just correct it. This is identical to the other one, no need for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. When you take the square root of $(x-1)^2$ you get $|x-1|$, not $x-1$ itself. So now you have to solve
$$ \sqrt y = |x-1| $$
There will be solutions corresponding to $x-1$ being either positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks, I ask because if I have $\int_{0}^{1}(-5y+1)$, I would have to do it twice (one in which $y$ is positive and another when it is negative), right?

Comment: Omega: Do you mean $\int_0^1 (-5y+1)\,dy$? In the case $y$ is explicitly never negative.

Comment: Not to be overly pedantic, but this assumes we're talking about real variables here. Of course, this is probably the case, so you're right.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If I had $\int_{0}^{1}(x)dy$, I would need to isolate the $x$ from my $y = (x-1)^2$ - if I did that, $x$ could be either $-\sqrt{y}+1$ or $\sqrt{y}+1$ and I'd have to do both cases?

Comment: @Omega: $\int_0^1 x\,dy$ is just $x$, no squares involved. I don't see what that integral has to do with your question.